# How to make Boost.Spirit.Lex token value be a substring of matched sequence (preferably by regex matching group)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-lex

I'm writing a simple expressions parser. It is build on a Boost.Spirit.Qi grammar based on Boost.Spirit.Lex tokens (Boost in version 1.56).

The tokens are defined as follows:

```
using namespace boost::spirit;

template<
    typename lexer_t
>
struct tokens
    : lex::lexer<lexer_t>
{
    tokens()
        : /* ... */,
          variable("%(\\w+)")
    {
        this->self =
            /* ... */ |
            variable;
    }

    /* ... */
    lex::token_def<std::string> variable;
};
```

Now I would like the `variable` token value to be just the name (the matching group `(\\w+)`) without prefix `%` symbol. How do I do that?

---

Using a matching group by itself doesn't help. Still value is full string, including the prefix `%`.

Is there any way to force using of a matching group?

Or in at least somehow refer to it within action of the token?

---

I tried also using action like this:

```
variable[lex::_val = std::string(lex::_start + 1, lex::_end)]
```

but it failed to compile. Error claimed that none of the `std::string` constructor overloads could match arguments:

```
(const boost::phoenix::actor<Expr>, const boost::spirit::lex::_end_type)
```

---

Even simpler

```
variable[lex::_val = std::string(lex::_start, lex::_end)]
```

failed to compile. With similar reason only first argument type was now `boost::spirit::lex::_start_type`.

---

Finally I tried this (even though it looks like a big waste):

```
lex::_val = std::string(lex::_val).erase(0, 1)
```

but that also failed to compile. This time compiler was unable to convert from `const boost::spirit::lex::_val_type` to `std::string`.

---

Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Comment: For your simple examples search for `phoenix::construct`, for anything more complex a `phoenix::function` (possibly with an adapting macro) would be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

## Simple Solution

Correct form of constructing the `std::string` attribute value is following:

```
variable[lex::_val = boost::phoenix::construct<std::string>(lex::_start + 1, lex::_end)]
```

exactly as suggested by [jv_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2417774/jv) in his (or her) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476454/how-to-make-boost-spirit-lex-token-value-be-a-substring-of-matched-sequence-pre#comment58648155_35476454).

`boost::phoenix::construct` is provided by `<boost/phoenix/object/construct.hpp>` header. Or use `<boost/phoenix.hpp>`.

## Regular Expression Solution

The above solution however works well only in simple cases. And excludes the possibility to have the pattern provided from outside (from configuration data in particular). Since changing the pattern for example to `%(\\w+)%` would require to change the value construction code.

That is why it would be much better to be able to refer to capture groups from the regular expression defining the token.

*Now note that this still isn't perfect since weird cases like `%(\\w+)%(\\w+)%` would still require change in the code to be handled correctly. That could be worked around by configuring not only the regex for the token but also means to form the value from the matched range. Yet this goes out of the scope of the question. Using capture groups directly seems flexible enough for many cases.*

[sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468928/using-lexer-token-attributes-in-grammar-rules-with-lex-and-qi-from-boost-spirit?noredirect=1#comment66312122_39468928) elsewhere stated, that there is no way to use capture groups from token's regular expression. Not to mention that tokens actually support only a subset of regular expressions. (Among notable differences there is for example lack of support for naming capture groups or ignoring them!).

My own experiments in this area support that as well. There is no way to use capture groups sadly. There is a workaround however - you have to just re-apply the regex in your action.

### Action Obtaining Capture Range

To make it a little bit modular let's start with a simplest task - an action which returns `boost::iterator_range` part of the token's match corresponding to specified capture.

```
template<typename Attribute, typename Char, typename Idtype>
class basic_get_capture
{
public:
    typedef lex::token_def<Attribute, Char, Idtype> token_type;
    typedef boost::basic_regex<Char> regex_type;

    explicit basic_get_capture(token_type const& token, int capture_index = 1)
        : token(token),
          regex(),
          capture_index(capture_index)
    {
    }

    template<typename Iterator, typename IdType, typename Context>
    boost::iterator_range<Iterator> operator ()(Iterator& first, Iterator& last, lex::pass_flags& /*flag*/, IdType& /*id*/, Context& /*context*/)
    {
        typedef boost::match_results<Iterator> match_results_type;

        match_results_type results;
        regex_match(first, last, results, get_regex());
        typename match_results_type::const_reference capture = results[capture_index];
        return boost::iterator_range<Iterator>(capture.first, capture.second);
    }

private:
    regex_type& get_regex()
    {
        if(regex.empty())
        {
            token_type::string_type const& regex_text = token.definition();
            regex.assign(regex_text);
        }
        return regex;
    }

    token_type const& token;
    regex_type regex;
    int capture_index;
};

template<typename Attribute, typename Char, typename Idtype>
basic_get_capture<Attribute, Char, Idtype> get_capture(lex::token_def<Attribute, Char, Idtype> const& token, int capture_index = 1)
{
    return basic_get_capture<Attribute, Char, Idtype>(token, capture_index);
}
```

The action uses [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/) (include `<boost/regex.hpp>`).

### Action Obtaining Capture as String

Now as the capture range is a nice thing to have as it doesn't allocate any new memory for the string, it is the string that we want in the end after all. So here another action build upon the previous one.

```
template<typename Attribute, typename Char, typename Idtype>
class basic_get_capture_as_string
{
public:
    typedef basic_get_capture<Attribute, Char, Idtype> basic_get_capture_type;
    typedef typename basic_get_capture_type::token_type token_type;

    explicit basic_get_capture_as_string(token_type const& token, int capture_index = 1)
        : get_capture_functor(token, capture_index)
    {
    }

    template<typename Iterator, typename IdType, typename Context>
    std::basic_string<Char> operator ()(Iterator& first, Iterator& last, lex::pass_flags& flag, IdType& id, Context& context)
    {
        boost::iterator_range<Iterator> const& capture = get_capture_functor(first, last, flag, id, context);
        return std::basic_string<Char>(capture.begin(), capture.end());
    }

private:
    basic_get_capture_type get_capture_functor;
};

template<typename Attribute, typename Char, typename Idtype>
basic_get_capture_as_string<Attribute, Char, Idtype> get_capture_as_string(lex::token_def<Attribute, Char, Idtype> const& token, int capture_index = 1)
{
    return basic_get_capture_as_string<Attribute, Char, Idtype>(token, capture_index);
}
```

No magic here. We just make an `std::basic_string` from the range returned by the simpler action.

### Action Assigning Value From the Capture

Actions that return a value are of little use for us. Ultimate goal is to set token value from the capture. And this is done by the last action.

```
template<typename Attribute, typename Char, typename Idtype>
class basic_set_val_from_capture
{
public:
    typedef basic_get_capture_as_string<Attribute, Char, Idtype> basic_get_capture_as_string_type;
    typedef typename basic_get_capture_as_string_type::token_type token_type;

    explicit basic_set_val_from_capture(token_type const& token, int capture_index = 1)
        : get_capture_as_string_functor(token, capture_index)
    {
    }

    template<typename Iterator, typename IdType, typename Context>
    void operator ()(Iterator& first, Iterator& last, lex::pass_flags& flag, IdType& id, Context& context)
    {
        std::basic_string<Char> const& capture = get_capture_as_string_functor(first, last, flag, id, context);
        context.set_value(capture);
    }

private:
    basic_get_capture_as_string_type get_capture_as_string_functor;
};

template<typename Attribute, typename Char, typename Idtype>
basic_set_val_from_capture<Attribute, Char, Idtype> set_val_from_capture(lex::token_def<Attribute, Char, Idtype> const& token, int capture_index = 1)
{
    return basic_set_val_from_capture<Attribute, Char, Idtype>(token, capture_index);
}
```

### Discussion

The actions are used like this:

```
variable[set_val_from_capture(variable)]
```

Optionally you can provide a second argument being the index of capture to use. It defaults to `1` which seems suitable in most cases.

**Creating Functions**

`set_val_from_capture` (or `get_capture_as_string` or `get_capture` respectively) is an auxiliary function used for automatic deduction of template arguments from the `token_def`. In particular what we need is the `Char` type to make corresponding regular expression.

I'm not sure if this could be reasonably avoided and even if so then it would significantly complicated the call operator (especially if we would strive to cache the regex object instead of building it each time anew). My doubts come mostly from not being sure whether `Char` type of `token_def` is required to be the same as the tokenized sequence character type or not. I assumed that they don't have to be the same.

**Repeating the Token**

Definitely unpleasant part of the action is the need to provide the token itself as an argument making a repetition.

The token is however needed for the `Char` type as described above *and* to... get the regular expression!

It seems to me that at least in theory we could be able to obtain the token somehow "at run-time" based on `id` argument to the action (which we just ignore currently). However I failed to find any way how to obtain `token_def` based on token's identifier regardless whether from `context` argument or the lexer itself (which could be passed to the action as `this` through creating function).

**Reusability**

Since those are actions they are not really reusable (out of the box) in more complex scenarios. For example if you would like to not only get just the capture but also convert it to some numeric value you would have to write another action this way instead of making a complex action at the token.

At first I tried to achieve something like this:

```
variable[lex::_val = get_capture_as_string(variable)]
```

It seems like more flexible as you could easily add more code around it - like for example wrap it in some conversion function.

But I failed to achieve it. Although I feel like I didn't try hard enough. Learning more about [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/libs/phoenix/) would surely help here a lot.

**Double Work**

All this workaround doesn't prevent us from doing double work. Both at regex parsing and then matching. But as mentioned in the beginning it seems that there is no better way (without altering Boost.Spirit itself).

Comment: Nice answer. [Here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mBAPm21JqR9Q8Apm) is an approach that uses an extra lexer state to deal with the prefix-variable_name relationship. It seems to work but I have based it only on my limited understanding of some examples and tests in the boost distribution so I can't be sure that it's correct.

Comment: @jv_ Interesting, thanks. Somehow I feel "afraid" of direct lexer state manipulation. Yet it's always better to know other approaches!

Comment: @jv_ I was about to. But then I thought to at least try to improve it more for which I will give myself some longer time (I'm pretty busy recently). Learning more on Boost.Spirit and Boost.Phoenix in the mean time surly will help!

Comment: Great attitude. Good luck in your efforts.