# Using lexer token attributes in grammar rules with Lex and Qi from Boost.Spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

Let's consider following code:

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

struct operation
{
    enum type
    {
        add,
        sub,
        mul,
        div
    };
};

template<typename Lexer>
class expression_lexer
    : public lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
public:
    typedef lex::token_def<operation::type> operator_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<double> value_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<std::string> variable_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<lex::omit> parenthesis_token_type;
    typedef std::pair<parenthesis_token_type, parenthesis_token_type> parenthesis_token_pair_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<lex::omit> whitespace_token_type;

    expression_lexer()
        : operator_add('+'),
          operator_sub('-'),
          operator_mul("[x*]"),
          operator_div("[:/]"),
          value("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"),
          variable("%(\\w+)"),
          parenthesis({
            std::make_pair(parenthesis_token_type('('), parenthesis_token_type(')')),
            std::make_pair(parenthesis_token_type('['), parenthesis_token_type(']'))
          }),
          whitespace("[ \\t]+")
    {
        this->self
            += operator_add [lex::_val = operation::add]
            | operator_sub [lex::_val = operation::sub]
            | operator_mul [lex::_val = operation::mul]
            | operator_div [lex::_val = operation::div]
            | value
            | variable [lex::_val = phoenix::construct<std::string>(lex::_start + 1, lex::_end)]
            | whitespace [lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore]
            ;

        std::for_each(parenthesis.cbegin(), parenthesis.cend(),
            [&](parenthesis_token_pair_type const& token_pair)
            {
                this->self += token_pair.first | token_pair.second;
            }
        );
    }

    operator_token_type operator_add;
    operator_token_type operator_sub;
    operator_token_type operator_mul;
    operator_token_type operator_div;

    value_token_type value;
    variable_token_type variable;

    std::vector<parenthesis_token_pair_type> parenthesis;

    whitespace_token_type whitespace;
};

template<typename Iterator>
class expression_grammar
    : public qi::grammar<Iterator>
{
public:
    template<typename Tokens>
    explicit expression_grammar(Tokens const& tokens)
        : expression_grammar::base_type(start)
    {
        start                     %= expression >> qi::eoi;

        expression                %= sum_operand >> -(sum_operator >> expression);
        sum_operator              %= tokens.operator_add | tokens.operator_sub;
        sum_operand               %= fac_operand >> -(fac_operator >> sum_operand);
        fac_operator              %= tokens.operator_mul | tokens.operator_div;

        if(!tokens.parenthesis.empty())
            fac_operand           %= parenthesised | terminal;
        else
            fac_operand           %= terminal;

        terminal                  %= tokens.value | tokens.variable;

        if(!tokens.parenthesis.empty())
        {
            parenthesised         %= tokens.parenthesis.front().first >> expression >> tokens.parenthesis.front().second;
            std::for_each(tokens.parenthesis.cbegin() + 1, tokens.parenthesis.cend(),
                [&](typename Tokens::parenthesis_token_pair_type const& token_pair)
                {
                    parenthesised %= parenthesised.copy() | (token_pair.first >> expression >> token_pair.second);
                }
            );
        }
    }

private:
    qi::rule<Iterator> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator> expression;
    qi::rule<Iterator> sum_operand;
    qi::rule<Iterator> sum_operator;
    qi::rule<Iterator> fac_operand;
    qi::rule<Iterator> fac_operator;
    qi::rule<Iterator> terminal;
    qi::rule<Iterator> parenthesised;
};


int main()
{
    typedef lex::lexertl::token<std::string::const_iterator, boost::mpl::vector<operation::type, double, std::string>> token_type;
    typedef expression_lexer<lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<token_type>> expression_lexer_type;
    typedef expression_lexer_type::iterator_type expression_lexer_iterator_type;
    typedef expression_grammar<expression_lexer_iterator_type> expression_grammar_type;

    expression_lexer_type lexer;
    expression_grammar_type grammar(lexer);

    while(std::cin)
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);

        std::string::const_iterator first = line.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator const last = line.end();

        bool const result = lex::tokenize_and_parse(first, last, lexer, grammar);
        if(!result)
            std::cout << "Parsing failed! Reminder: >" << std::string(first, last) << "<" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            if(first != last)
                std::cout << "Parsing succeeded! Reminder: >" << std::string(first, last) << "<" << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "Parsing succeeded!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

It is a simple parser for arithmetic expressions with values and variables. It is build using `expression_lexer` for extracting tokens, and then with `expression_grammar` to parse the tokens.

Use of lexer for such a small case might seem an overkill and probably is one. But that is the cost of simplified example. Also note that use of lexer allows to easily define tokens with regular expression while that allows to easily define them by external code (and user provided configuration in particular). With the example provided it would be no issue at all to read definition of tokens from an external config file and for example allow user to change variables from `%name` to `$name`.

The code seems to be working fine (checked on Visual Studio 2013 with Boost 1.61).

The `expression_lexer` has attributes attached to tokens. I guess they work since they compile. But I don't really know how to check.

Ultimately I would like the grammar to build me an `std::vector` with reversed polish notation of the expression. (Where every element would be a `boost::variant` over either `operator::type` or `double` or `std::string`.)

The problem is however that I failed to use token attributes in my `expression_grammar`. For example if you try to change `sum_operator` following way:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, operation::type ()> sum_operator;
```

you will get compilation error. I expected this to work since `operation::type` is the attribute for both `operator_add` and `operator_sub` and so also for their alternative. And still it doesn't compile. Judging from the error in `assign_to_attribute_from_iterators` it seems that parser tries to build the attribute value directly from input stream range. Which means it ignores the `[lex::_val = operation::add]` I specified in my lexer.

Changing that to

```
qi::rule<Iterator, operation::type (operation::type)> sum_operator;
```

didn't help either.

Also I tried changing definition to

```
sum_operator %= (tokens.operator_add | tokens.operator_sub) [qi::_val = qi::_1];
```

didn't help either.

How to work around that? I know I could use `symbols` from Qi. But I want to have the lexer to make it easy to configure regexes for the tokens. I could also extend the `assign_to_attribute_from_iterators` as described in the documentation but this kind of double the work. I guess I could also skip the attributes on lexer and just have them on grammar. But this again doesn't work well with flexibility on `variable` token (in my actual case there is slightly more logic there so that it is configurable also which part of the token forms actual name of the variable - while here it is fixed to just skip the first character). Anything else?

---

Also a side question - maybe anyone knows. Is there a way to get to capture groups of the regular expression of the token from tokens action? So that instead of having

```
variable [lex::_val = phoenix::construct<std::string>(lex::_start + 1, lex::_end)]
```

instead I would be able to make a string from the capture group and so easily handle formats like `$var$`.

---

Edited! I have improved whitespace skipping along conclusions from [Whitespace skipper when using Boost.Spirit Qi and Lex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468278/whitespace-skipper-when-using-boost-spirit-qi-and-lex). It is a simplification that does not affect questions asked here.

Comment: Re "side question [...] capture groups of [...] of the token" - you can't. They are not regular expressions. The syntax closely resembles a subset of that, yes.

Comment: I'd parse into AST, then transform to RPN. I'll complete an example when I have time, here's for now: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b01dfd4898103ba5

Comment: @sehe Based on your comment above and some experience I gathered along I was finally able to answer my own previous question in this area http://stackoverflow.com/a/39510064/422489. You might want to have a look whether there is anything more to add or extend.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here's my take on the RPN 'requirement'. I heavily favor natural (automatic) attribute propagation over semantic actions (see [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil))

I consider the other options (uglifying) optimizations. You might do them if you're happy with the overall design and don't mind making it harder to maintain :)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9f2a16d0c74d4b2)</kbd>**

Beyond the sample from my comment that you've already studied, I added that RPN transformation step:

```
namespace RPN {
    using cell      = boost::variant<AST::operation, AST::value, AST::variable>;
    using rpn_stack = std::vector<cell>;

    struct transform : boost::static_visitor<> {
        void operator()(rpn_stack& stack, AST::expression const& e) const {
            boost::apply_visitor(boost::bind(*this, boost::ref(stack), ::_1), e);
        }
        void operator()(rpn_stack& stack, AST::bin_expr const& e) const {
            (*this)(stack, e.lhs);
            (*this)(stack, e.rhs);
            stack.push_back(e.op);
        }
        void operator()(rpn_stack& stack, AST::value    const& v) const { stack.push_back(v); }
        void operator()(rpn_stack& stack, AST::variable const& v) const { stack.push_back(v); }
    };
}
```

That's all! Use it like so, e.g.:

```
RPN::transform compiler;
RPN::rpn_stack program;
compiler(program, expr);

for (auto& instr : program) {
    std::cout << instr << " ";
}
```

Which makes the output:

```
Parsing success: (3 + (8 * 9))
3 8 9 * +
```

#### Full Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9f2a16d0c74d4b2)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace lex     = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace qi      = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

struct operation
{
    enum type
    {
        add,
        sub,
        mul,
        div
    };

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, type op) {
        switch (op) {
            case type::add: return os << "+";
            case type::sub: return os << "-";
            case type::mul: return os << "*";
            case type::div: return os << "/";
        }
        return os << "<" << static_cast<int>(op) << ">";
    }
};

template<typename Lexer>
class expression_lexer
    : public lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
public:
    //typedef lex::token_def<operation::type> operator_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<lex::omit> operator_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<double> value_token_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<std::string> variable_token_type;

    typedef lex::token_def<lex::omit> parenthesis_token_type;
    typedef std::pair<parenthesis_token_type, parenthesis_token_type> parenthesis_token_pair_type;
    typedef lex::token_def<lex::omit> whitespace_token_type;

    expression_lexer()
        : operator_add('+'),
          operator_sub('-'),
          operator_mul("[x*]"),
          operator_div("[:/]"),
          value("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"),
          variable("%(\\w+)"),
          parenthesis({
            std::make_pair(parenthesis_token_type('('), parenthesis_token_type(')')),
            std::make_pair(parenthesis_token_type('['), parenthesis_token_type(']'))
          }),
          whitespace("[ \\t]+")
    {
        this->self
            += operator_add [lex::_val = operation::add]
             | operator_sub [lex::_val = operation::sub]
             | operator_mul [lex::_val = operation::mul]
             | operator_div [lex::_val = operation::div]
             | value
             | variable [lex::_val = phoenix::construct<std::string>(lex::_start + 1, lex::_end)]
             | whitespace [lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore]
             ;

        std::for_each(parenthesis.cbegin(), parenthesis.cend(),
            [&](parenthesis_token_pair_type const& token_pair)
            {
                this->self += token_pair.first | token_pair.second;
            }
        );
    }

    operator_token_type operator_add;
    operator_token_type operator_sub;
    operator_token_type operator_mul;
    operator_token_type operator_div;

    value_token_type value;
    variable_token_type variable;

    std::vector<parenthesis_token_pair_type> parenthesis;

    whitespace_token_type whitespace;
};

namespace AST {
    using operation = operation::type;

    using value     = double;
    using variable  = std::string;

    struct bin_expr;
    using expression = boost::variant<value, variable, boost::recursive_wrapper<bin_expr> >;

    struct bin_expr {
        expression lhs, rhs;
        operation op;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, bin_expr const& be) {
            return os << "(" << be.lhs << " " << be.op << " " << be.rhs << ")";
        }
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::bin_expr, lhs, op, rhs)

template<typename Iterator>
class expression_grammar : public qi::grammar<Iterator, AST::expression()>
{
public:
    template<typename Tokens>
    explicit expression_grammar(Tokens const& tokens)
        : expression_grammar::base_type(start)
    {
        start                     = expression >> qi::eoi;

        bin_sum_expr              = sum_operand >> sum_operator >> expression;
        bin_fac_expr              = fac_operand >> fac_operator >> sum_operand;

        expression                = bin_sum_expr | sum_operand;
        sum_operand               = bin_fac_expr | fac_operand;

        sum_operator              = tokens.operator_add >> qi::attr(AST::operation::add) | tokens.operator_sub >> qi::attr(AST::operation::sub);
        fac_operator              = tokens.operator_mul >> qi::attr(AST::operation::mul) | tokens.operator_div >> qi::attr(AST::operation::div);

        if(tokens.parenthesis.empty()) {
            fac_operand           = terminal;
        }
        else {
            fac_operand           = parenthesised | terminal;

            parenthesised         = tokens.parenthesis.front().first >> expression >> tokens.parenthesis.front().second;
            std::for_each(tokens.parenthesis.cbegin() + 1, tokens.parenthesis.cend(),
                    [&](typename Tokens::parenthesis_token_pair_type const& token_pair)
                    {
                        parenthesised = parenthesised.copy() | (token_pair.first >> expression >> token_pair.second);
                    });
        }

        terminal                  = tokens.value | tokens.variable;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (start) (expression) (bin_sum_expr) (bin_fac_expr)
                (fac_operand) (terminal) (parenthesised) (sum_operand)
                (sum_operator) (fac_operator)
            );
    }

private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::expression()> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::expression()> expression;
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::expression()> sum_operand;
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::expression()> fac_operand;
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::expression()> terminal;
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::expression()> parenthesised;

    qi::rule<Iterator, int()> sum_operator;
    qi::rule<Iterator, int()> fac_operator;

    // extra rules to help with AST creation
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::bin_expr()> bin_sum_expr;
    qi::rule<Iterator, AST::bin_expr()> bin_fac_expr;
};

namespace RPN {
    using cell      = boost::variant<AST::operation, AST::value, AST::variable>;
    using rpn_stack = std::vector<cell>;

    struct transform : boost::static_visitor<> {
        void operator()(rpn_stack& stack, AST::expression const& e) const {
            boost::apply_visitor(boost::bind(*this, boost::ref(stack), ::_1), e);
        }
        void operator()(rpn_stack& stack, AST::bin_expr const& e) const {
            (*this)(stack, e.lhs);
            (*this)(stack, e.rhs);
            stack.push_back(e.op);
        }
        void operator()(rpn_stack& stack, AST::value    const& v) const { stack.push_back(v); }
        void operator()(rpn_stack& stack, AST::variable const& v) const { stack.push_back(v); }
    };
}

int main()
{
    typedef lex::lexertl::token<std::string::const_iterator, boost::mpl::vector<operation::type, double, std::string>> token_type;
    typedef expression_lexer<lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<token_type>> expression_lexer_type;
    typedef expression_lexer_type::iterator_type expression_lexer_iterator_type;
    typedef expression_grammar<expression_lexer_iterator_type> expression_grammar_type;

    expression_lexer_type lexer;
    expression_grammar_type grammar(lexer);
    RPN::transform compiler;

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty())
    {
        std::string::const_iterator first = line.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator const last = line.end();

        AST::expression expr;
        bool const result = lex::tokenize_and_parse(first, last, lexer, grammar, expr);
        if(!result)
            std::cout << "Parsing failed!\n";
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Parsing success: " << expr << "\n";

            RPN::rpn_stack program;
            compiler(program, expr);

            for (auto& instr : program) {
                std::cout << instr << " ";
            }
        }

        if(first != last)
            std::cout << "Remainder: >" << std::string(first, last) << "<\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Main point was how to use Lex token attribute in Qi rules. Which you didn't seem to answer directly. Indirectly, I noted that you skipped the `operation::type` attribute on operator token type and instead (I guess it works like that) you are artificially injecting the attribute from within the grammar itself (with `qi::attr`). While that works you provided no explanation on why you have done it that way. (Especially that you kept lexer's actions for operators - did you forgot to remove them?) I will think on it more before accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Also recently I noticed that unlike what I thought earlier the `value` token's attribute (`double`) isn't magically build out of the token's matched range. Instead the value of the token is the matched range. Even though no such type is listed in `mpl::vector` of `token_type` - it seems to be added by "template magic". Which makes the `double` attribute on the `value` token kind of pointless... (Unless - I guess - I will make appropriate semantic action for it...)

Comment: Also would you care to explain the `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` and why it lists members in different order? Is it done to let Qi automatically synthesis attribute for the `bin_sum_expr` and `bin_fac_expr` rules?

Comment: This is (unsurprisingly) a pretty great answer. The only thing I feel is missing is a warning about situations like [this one](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3XslypThfEUi5gH8).

Comment: So far my investigations make me think that the problem is narrower than I originally thought. Lexer token attributes are normally treated in Qi. _Except_ for those which are `enum` types. So far I don't know why it happens so. But it may be that your trick with `qi::attr` instead will be needed. But why is it so?

Comment: (lack of) implicit conversions. I'd make an explicit parser for the enum. But then, I'd use `enum class` and Spirit X3