# Converting a Boost Spirit Lex semantic action to Phoenix - How to access _val?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix, boost-spirit-lex

I wrote a semantic action for my Boost Spirit Lexer to convert escape sequences in strings to what they stand for. It works perfectly and I want to convert it to a Boost Phoenix expression, but can't get that one to compile.

Here is what works:

```
// the semantic action
struct ConvertEscapes
{
    template <typename ItT, typename IdT, typename CtxT>
    void operator () (ItT& start, ItT& end, lex::pass_flags& matched, IdT& id, CtxT& ctx)
    {
        static boost::wregex escapeRgx(L"(\\\\r)|(\\\\n)|(\\\\t)|(\\\\\\\\)|(\\\\\")");
        static std::wstring escapeRepl = L"(?1\r)(?2\n)(?3\t)(?4\\\\)(?5\")";
        static std::wstring wval; // static b/c set_value doesn't seem to copy

        auto const& val = ctx.get_value();
        wval.assign(val.begin(), val.end());
        wval = boost::regex_replace(wval, 
                                    escapeRgx, 
                                    escapeRepl, 
                                    boost::match_default | boost::format_all);
        ctx.set_value(wval);
    }
};

// the token declaration
lex::token_def<std::wstring, wchar_t> literal_str;

// the token definition
literal_str  = L"\\\"([^\\\\\"]|(\\\\.))*\\\""; // string with escapes

// adding it to the lexer
this->self += literal_str [ ConvertEscapes() ];
```

---

This is what I tried to convert it:

```
this->self += literal_str 
[ 
    lex::_val = boost::regex_replace(lex::_val /* this is the place I can't figure out */,
                                     boost::wregex(L"(\\\\r)|(\\\\n)|
                                     (\\\\t)|(\\\\\\\\)|(\\\\\")"), 
                                     L"(?1\r)(?2\n)(?3\t)(?4\\\\)(?5\")", 
                                     boost::match_default | boost::format_all) 
];
```

A `wstring` can't be constructed from `_val`. `_val` also doesn't have `begin()` or `end()`, how is it supposed to be used anyway?

This `std::wstring(lex::_start, lex::_end)` fails, too, because those arguments aren't recognized as iterators.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468928/using-lexer-token-attributes-in-grammar-rules-with-lex-and-qi-from-boost-spirit), I found `phoenix::construct<std::wstring>(lex::_start, lex::_end)`, but this also doesn't really result in a `wstring`.

How do I get either a string or a pair of `wchar_t` iterators for the current token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to chant the oft-heard "Why"?

This time, for good reason.

In general, avoid semantic actions: [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil).

Phoenix Actors are needlessly more complex than the dedicated functor. They have a sweet point (mainly simple assignment or builtin operations). But if the actor is any kind of non-trivial you'll see the complexity ramp up quickly, not just for the human but also for the compiler. This leads to

- slow compilation
- sub-optimal emitted code
- harder to maintain source
- new classes of error (e.g. when the expression templates hold references to locals/temporaries, something that Boost Proto (and hence Phoenix) does *not* prevent or signal. In fact, it encourages it by assuming all template expressions are ephemeral, but I digress).

> Interestingly: Spirit X3 dropped Phoenix altogether, even though Phoenix was once the brain child of Spirit³.
>
> The new style uses c++14 polymorphic lambdas, that look 90% like the helper function object in the original code, but inline as a lambda.

#### This specific case

Can't work. At all.

The problem is that you're mixing lazy/deferred actors with direct invocations. That can never work. The type of `phoenix::construct<std::wstring>(lex::_start, lex::_end)` isn't *supposed* to be `std::wstring`. Of course. It is *supposed to be* a lazy actor¹ that can be used at some later time to create a `std::wstring`.

Now that we know that (and why) `phoenix::construct<std::wstring>(lex::_start, lex::_end)` is an actor type, it should become clear why it is completely bogus to call `boost::regex_replace` on it. You might as well say

```
struct implementation_defined {} bogus;
boost::regex_replace(bogus, re, fmt, boost::match_default | boost::format_all);
```

And wonder why it would not compile.

#### Summary:

You should probably just have the dedicated functor. You *can* of course Phoenix-adapt the regex functions you require, but all it does is shift the complexity tax for some syntactic sugar.

I'd always opt for the more naive approach that is going to be more understandable to a seasoned c++ programmer, and avoids pitfalls that come with high-wire acts².

Nevertheless, here's a pointer should you be curious:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/function.html

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de3dd9ea860a72a3)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexer.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex.hpp>

namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;

BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(std::wstring, regex_replace_, boost::regex_replace, 4)

template <typename... T>
struct Lexer : lex::lexer<T...> {
    Lexer() {
        // the token definition
        literal_str  = L"\\\"([^\\\\\"]|(\\\\.))*\\\""; // string with escapes

        // adding it to the lexer
        this->self += literal_str [
            lex::_val = regex_replace_(lex::_val,
                 boost::wregex(L"(\\\\r)|(\\\\n)|(\\\\t)|(\\\\\\\\)|(\\\\\")"), 
                 L"(?1\r)(?2\n)(?3\t)(?4\\\\)(?5\")", 
                 boost::match_default | boost::format_all) 

        ];
    }

    // the token declaration
    lex::token_def<std::wstring, wchar_t> literal_str;
};

int main() {
    typedef lex::lexertl::token<std::wstring::const_iterator, boost::mpl::vector<std::wstring, wchar_t>> token_type;
    typedef Lexer<lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<token_type>> lexer_type;
    typedef lexer_type::iterator_type lexer_iterator_type;
}
```

---

¹ think composed function object that can be invoked at a later time

² the balance might tip if you were designing this as an EDSL for further configuration by non-experts, but then you will have the added responsibility of documenting your EDSL and the constraints in which it can be used

³ should we say, spirit-child of a brain?

Comment: Why … I read "[Even if it is possible to write your own function object implementations(...), the preferred way of defining lexer semantic actions is to use Boost.Phoenix.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/abstracts/lexer_semantic_actions.html#spirit.lex.abstracts.lexer_semantic_actions.lexer_semantic_actions_using_phoenix)" (thanks for clearing that up.) I planned to stick with the functor because the regex is `static` in there, but wanted to learn. Thanks for giving so much detail, I've read many helpful answers on Spirit from you and this is another one.

Comment: Cheers. I suppose the advice is both true though. Use Phoenix while you can - and I'd mostly say think twice before doing anything more :)